# Lists in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have three lists :
`HeaderList : [A, B, C]`
`SubHeaderList : [a1, a2, b1, b2, b3, c1]`
`HeaderSubHeaderMapping : [2, 3, 1]`

I need to create a new list which will be : `[A_a1, A_a2, B_b1, B_b2, B_b3, C_c1]`
The HeaderSubHeaderMapping gives how many subheaders in the SubHeaderList belong to headers in the HeaderList.
For example : `Header A` will have `2` subheaders `a1` and `a2` as indicated by the `HeaderSubHeaderMapping` 
I am currently using this code which gives me the required output.

```
def lHeaderList = ["A", "B", "C"]
def lSubHeaderList = ["a1", "a2", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1"]
def lHeaderSubHeaderMapping = [2, 3, 1]

def lKeyList = []
def lIndex = 0
for(int i = 0; i < lHeaderList.size(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < lHeaderSubHeaderMapping.get(i); j++) {
        lKeyList << (lHeaderList.get(i) + "_" + lSubHeaderList.get(lIndex))
        lIndex++
    }
}
println lKeyList
```

But I would like to know is there any groovier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something I could come up with right now:

```
int i=0
def result=[]

[lHeaderList, lHeaderSubHeaderMapping].transpose().collectEntries {it}
    .collect {h, t-> t.times {result << "${h}_${lSubHeaderList[i++]}"} }    

println result
```

But I think it may be refined further.

Comment: This is a nice solution.

We can get rid of the variable `i` if we use `${h}_${lSubHeaderList.remove(0)}` instead of `${h}_${lSubHeaderList[i++]}`